# Unable to play a sequence of images while clicking on a button

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to play separated images of an animated image by clicking on the next button. Image names were stored as strings in an array. When I click on next button, the image transition is happening for the first time. Next time, it is not happening. When I tried to print the value of i, to check what is happening when the next button is clicked, the value is not getting incremented. Below is my code:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image2: UIImageView!
    // @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!

  //        img1.image=UIImage(named:"frame2.gif")

    @IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
        var imgarray=["frame2.gif","frame3.gif","frame4.gif","frame5.gif","frame6.gif"]
        var i=0
        if i<7{
            image2.image=UIImage(named:imgarray[i])
            i+=1
        }
        else if i>=7{
            i=0
        }
               print(i)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `var i=0` outside the button action. Otherwise when you click on button your `i` will always reinitialize with `0`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var i=0
    @IBOutlet weak var image2: UIImageView!
    // @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!

  //        img1.image=UIImage(named:"frame2.gif")

    @IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
        var imgarray=["frame2.gif","frame3.gif","frame4.gif","frame5.gif","frame6.gif"]

        if i<7{
            image2.image=UIImage(named:imgarray[i])
            i+=1
        }
        else if i>=7{
            i=0
        }
               print(i)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you! I initialized the variable i in the wrong place.

Comment: var i = 0 position

Comment: put var i=0 out side the button action. when you click on button then your i always reinslise with 0

Comment: Yes, your code worked. I edited my previous comment. I can accept the answer after only 5 minutes